# Ipad Mini is locked!

Tags: ipad, password

I just recently received my iPad Mini as a reward from my principal, and it was working just fine. I bought it home with me because it is now my property. Then, this morning, I turn it on and see that I need to put in a password! I never input a password, so can anyone tell me why this just happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your school, or school district, has the device under control of an MDM which can set a lock code remotely. This action may have been accidental, or deliberate, but your only recourse is to ask the IT department to fix it for you.

This functionality, and many other options, is available in Meraki, and I have used it myself.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it was brand new, and it hadn't been opened from its package

Comment: After you turned it on for the first time, it is possible the iPad was configured 'behind your back' by the MDM system, and the lock settings were configured then. Again, talk with your IT staff.